# The panel encountered a problem while loading "OAFIID:GNOME_Panel_TrashApplet" What does it mean?

Tags: gnome-panel

`The panel encountered a problem while loading "OAFIID:GNOME_Panel_TrashApplet"` 
What does it mean? What is `OAFIID:GNOME_Panel_TrashApplet`?

[image: fail]

Should I click Don't Delete or Delete?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click Don't Delete. Clicking Delete will Delete it from your panel, when sometimes you may want it. I suggest checking if it is even installed by trying to add it to panel. See RIGHT CLICK Panel > Add to Panel...

If it happens again or if it is not on the list try this:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall gnome-applets
```

Comment: Ah so it means just trash icon? but it never was on my panel before why I got this error?

Comment: Which Ubuntu Version is this? Also, If you are on 11.04 (using Classic) or lower, it was beside "Workspaces" on the bottom right.

Comment: 10.04 ah yeah i remember it was somewhere at the bottom but now there isn't but i still haven't restarted so maybe it appear next time

Comment: it's here after restart